# Check a div and add a class to a related div?

Tags: jquery

**What I have**

I am making an interactive-step map and am using SVGs to handle the drawing. I want it to check on load how many divs are in X (an rss feed), then apply an incrementing class to each. I am doing this like so:

```
$(".gs-rss-feed .rss-item").each(function(i) {
  $(this).addClass("step" + (i + 1));
}
```

For the sake of explanation, we'll call this "RSS-Step". So now each rss-item has a class of `step+i`.

I will also need to access my svg, each item has a class of just `circle`, so I want to increment those as well (these have to be separately incremented). There can be more of these "Map-Steps" than RSS items at one time.

```
$(".map .circle").each(function(j) {
  $(this).addClass("circle" + (j + 1));
}
```

At this point, I should have a `map` div of 23 circles named `circle+j` and an `gs-rss-feed` div of ***up to*** 23 items, named `step+i`.

---

**What I'm having trouble figuring out**

Now that I have those divs, I want to check if there is a relevant `step` for each `circle`. Basically if there is a `circle-7`, check if there is a `step-7`, then add a class to `circle-7`. I could do this with 23 conditionals, but would rather find a way to do this in a loop to minimize the code.

So far, I have something like this:

*Check if steps length is greater than 0, then check if that circle length is also greater than 0, if true, add `filled`.*

```
if($('.gs-rss-feed .step' + i.length > 0 && $('.map .circle') + j.length > 0 )){
    $('.bridge'+this).addClass('filled');
  }
```

I think ultimately I am having trouble trying to figure out how to check if the `i` value of a class is = to the `j` value of another class. If they were equal, then it would be like saying:

`step1` exists, `circle1` exists, add class `filled` to `circle1`

---

Appreciate any help you guys can give me! Thanks :)

Comment: step-7 is nested in circle-7?

Comment: @TonySamperi I should have clarified, the parent div `.map` is outside of the other parent div `.gs-rss-feed`. The only nested divs would be `circle` in `map` and `step` in `gs-rss-feed`.

Comment: So `.map > .gs-rss-feed > step` and `.map > circle` there's no relationship between circle and step

Comment: @TonySamperi I would say more like this, where the two `map` + `gs-rss-feed` aren't in a parent/child relationship. **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b70gycyk/1/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you have to use *eq()*. 
*eq()* returns the index of the selected element in a set.
*eq(n)* selects the nth element of a set.

you wrote:

> step1 exists, circle1 exists, add class filled to circle1

So basically you can select nth element. Then jQuery will do the rest. If no match is found no class will be added.

```
$(".gs-rss-feed .step").each(function(i){
    $(".map .circle").eq(i).addClass("filled");

});
```